# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target in wrapper method - Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Ok I'm guessing I'm missing something really simple on this one.

Lets say I have multiple methods that repeat a lot of the same things like this:

```
    public getDepartments(id: number): ng.IPromise<IDepartmentViewModel[]> {
        this.common.loadStart();
        return this.unitOfWork.teamRepository.getDepartmentsForTeam(id).then((response: IDepartmentViewModel[]) => {
            this.common.loadComplete();
            return response;
        }).catch((error) => {
                this.common.loadReset();
                return error;
            });
    }
```

Tons of boilerplate for a single call to `this.unitOfWork.teamRepository.getDepartmentsForTeam(id)`

so I wanted to make a generic wrapper for the boilerplate such as:

```
private internalCall<T>(method: () => ng.IPromise<T>): ng.IPromise<T> {
        this.common.loadStart();
        return method().then((response: T) => {
            this.common.loadComplete();
            return response;
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.common.loadReset();
            return error;
        });
    }
```

Which I could then call like:

```
public getDepartments(id: number): ng.IPromise<IDepartmentViewModel[]> {
        return this.internalCall<IDepartmentViewModel[]>(this.unitOfWork.teamRepository.getDepartmentsForTeam(id));
```

But I get the following error:

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
Type '() => ng.IPromise<IDepartmentViewModel[]>' requires a call signature, but type 'ng.IPromise<IDepartmentViewModel[]>' lacks one.
```

What is the right way to pass my method into the other to call it with supplied parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to wrap the call so it was wrapped in a closure like so:

```
public getDepartments(id: number): ng.IPromise<IDepartmentViewModel[]> {
    return this.internalCall<IDepartmentViewModel[]>(
        () => { return this.unitOfWork.teamRepository.getDepartmentsForTeam(id); } // Wrapping here too
    );
```

Answer (score 18):

This is a common mistake: you cannot pass a method function as a regular function since it requires the instance for the class as context. The solution is to use a closure:

```
function foo( func: () => any ) {
}
class A {
 method() : any {
 }
}
var instanceOfA = new A;

// Error: you need a closure to preserve the reference to instanceOfA
foo( instanceOfA.method ); 
// Correct: the closure preserves the binding to instanceOfA 
foo( () => instanceOfA.method() );
```

For a more complete example you can also see my [snippet](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/28601/Typescript--passing-a-class-member-funct) published here: http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/28601/Typescript--passing-a-class-member-funct

Answer (score 1):

Only for documentation - I got this error when I accidentally called the wrong (existing) function with wrong parameters. Had to look into the errorous line in the packaged file `.tmp/bla/bla/bla.ts` to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your fat arrow in to normal function. This will resolve the issue.
() => ng.IPromise 
to
function(){ng.IPromise .....}

Answer (score 0):

In my case a simpler trick allowed me to dodge the error. The call *(or trigger)* of a function is due to it parentheses, so :

```
class MyClass {
foo: any;

  firstMethod() {
     this.foo = this.secondMethod;
     this.foo();
  }

  secondMethod() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a more generic answer, the error *"Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target in wrapper method - Typescript"*  points out that you are calling a function with the wrong parameters.

example() receives two parameters per definition, but you are passing only one:

```
example('param1') // wrong
example('param1','param2') // OK!
```